# GCS - Overflow menu next to folder in bucket (three dots) no longer has Rename, Copy, etc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to rename a folder in a GCS bucket and the three dot menu to the right no longer has Rename, Copy, etc., it only has two options: **Scan with Cloud Data Loss Prevention** and **Export to Cloud Pub/Sub**.

Is it haunted? What's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

GCS objects does not support hierarchy and it is not easy to rename a folder or a bucket as it will be necessary to rename all the objects that are stored in that folder or bucket.

Comment: Taking this into account, a workaround could be to create a folder with the new name and simply copy the contents of the folder with the old name, then delete the folder with the old name